# How do I set a callback function for an OAuth2.0 Server with Password Grant Type?

Tags: php, web-services, rest, oauth-2.0, phalcon

I wanted to know if anyone can assist me on this, how do I set a Password grant type callback?
I have a working OAuth2.0 provider server running on my localhost and I just need to validate the user's credentials when requesting an access token.

I believe I just need to set a callback function. Herewith my code :

```
$app->setService('oauth', function() use ($config) {   
    $oauthdb = new \Twm\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mssql(
            $config
            ->database
            ->oauth
            ->toArray()
    );

    $server = new \League\OAuth2\Server\Authorization(
        new \Oauth2\Server\Storage\Pdo\Mssql\Client($oauthdb),
        new \Oauth2\Server\Storage\Pdo\Mssql\Session($oauthdb),
        new \Oauth2\Server\Storage\Pdo\Mssql\Scope($oauthdb)
    );

    $request = new \Oauth2\Server\Storage\Pdo\Mssql\Request(); 
    $server->setRequest($request);

    // do i set a callback here???

    $server->setAccessTokenTTL(86400);
    $server->addGrantType(new League\OAuth2\Server\Grant\Password($server));
    return $server;
});
```

If anybody can help I appreciate it, thanks!

**UPDATE**
So I read up on this subject here : https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-server/issues/97
It looks like that I indeed have to setup some kind of callback function to verify the user. I just need a little more help on this.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Alex, I implemented the Password verify routine below, and it works.

```
$app->setService('oauth', function() use ($config, $app) {   
    $oauthdb = new \Twm\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mssql(
        (array) $config->database->oauth
    );

    $server = new \League\OAuth2\Server\Authorization(
        new \Oauth2\Server\Storage\Pdo\Mssql\Client($oauthdb),
        new \Oauth2\Server\Storage\Pdo\Mssql\Session($oauthdb),
        new \Oauth2\Server\Storage\Pdo\Mssql\Scope($oauthdb)
    );

    # Not required as it called directly from original code
    # $request = new \League\OAuth2\Server\Util\Request();

    # add these 2 lines code if you want to use my own Request otherwise comment it
    $request = new \Oauth2\Server\Storage\Pdo\Mssql\Request(); 
    $server->setRequest($request);
    $server->setAccessTokenTTL(86400);        
    $grant = new League\OAuth2\Server\Grant\Password();
    $grant->setVerifyCredentialsCallback(function($username, $password){
        //echo "it works! ". $username . ' : ' . $password;        
        // if verified, then return true
        // else return false
    });
    $server->addGrantType($grant);        
    return $server;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the `setVerifyCredentialsCallback($callback)` method on the grant.

So altering your code slightly:

```
$request = new \Oauth2\Server\Storage\Pdo\Mssql\Request(); 
$server->setRequest($request);
$server->setAccessTokenTTL(86400);

$grant = new League\OAuth2\Server\Grant\Password($server);
$grant->setVerifyCredentialsCallback(function ($username, $password) {

   // your logic here - must return a user ID if credentials are valid or false if not

});

$server->addGrantType();
return $server;
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, can you perhaps explain when we use the getVerifyCredentialsCallback function?
eg.

 try {
        $params = $app->oauth->getParam(array('client_id', 'client_secret','username','password'));
        return $app->oauth
                ->getGrantType('password')
                ->completeFlow($params);
                //->getVerifyCredentialsCallback($params);                
    } catch (\League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\ClientException $e) {        
        echo $e->getTraceAsString();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getTraceAsString();
    }

Comment: Hi Alex I need your help again. How do I revoke an access_token?

Comment: Nevermind, revoking a token is easy. Just need to delete it from the oauth_sessions table :)